# Need a solution for an Electron application that uses a shared database

Tags: node.js, electron

I understand that node-mysql can be used for a database with Electron. However, if I build my app, the user will still need MySQL installed on their computer correct? I need a database solution that multiple users of my app can use without having any other dependancies installed. Just my standalone app. Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: Will the data in the database be the same for all users of your app? If not, then they have to have MySQL installed or your app connects to a remote server that holds the database (using the "host" parameter of the node-mysql connection function), without MySQL at your user's systems.

Comment: Yes it must be the same. Does this mean my app must connect to a remote server? Will they have to install any MySQL components on their computer, or will this all be contained in my electron app?

Comment: If it has to be the same database on all systems, you could use something like SQLite (as described in Akarsh Satija's answer below), which stores the databases in a file. You have got two answers with good approaches, so give them a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) inside your Electron application and set up a remote [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

PouchDB can work offline inside your application and can synchronize with CouchDB. If you use **sync**, every time the remote database changes, all connected applications will pull the latest changes to their local database.

**Sync** will be in two directions (if you want this, otherwise you can use **replicate**), so when an application makes a database change inside their local PouchDB, it will synchronize this to the remote CouchDB, and all the other applications will also pull this change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Correct would be to connect your electron app to a remote DB and setup an auth and set up DB behind that. You can also use DB's auth.

or if you can have individual DB per user. You can use Sqlite.